# Is inconsistent leading generally viewed unfavorably?

Tags: typography

See, for example, this partial image of a document.

[image: document showing inconsistent leading]

Comment: It annoys the crap out of *me*, that's for sure. Bullet leading should be the same for all kinds of bullets. Why would you make it different?

Comment: I've never heard "leading" used in that way, but I'm glad you, @Kurt, mentioned that. I was referring to leading as described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading.

Comment: Context matters. In that screen cap.. yeah it's bad. But it doesn't *always* have to be uniform.

Comment: I see two different bullets being used...both with different spacing between each. This isn't really an issue of leading--just formatting consistency in general. Yes, be consistent when you can.

Comment: I did not bring up the bullets, @DA01. I asked about leading.

Comment: @Brian unless you use a different definition than I do, the only leading I see there is between bulleted lines of text--and that's not normally considered leading as much as general paragraph/bullet level spacing. In other words, you would set leading for the text in each bullet point, but the space between bulleted sections would be something different than the leading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. (In the case of your image, it is bad.)

If you design a page layout using a baseline grid, it is perfectly fine to use different leadings if they fit the grid. For example, if you have a 3pt grid, leadings of 6, 9, 12, 15, etc are OK to use because they are multiples of 3. [This page](http://www.thinkingwithtype.com/contents/grid/) provides a pretty good explanation of baseline grids and how to use them effectively.

Looking at your image, the vertical spacing doesn't seem to follow any rule, and that would be considered "unfavorable". In fact, it looks more like someone used different space before/after properties or just inserted a blank paragraph between some of these elements (both of which are common for documents produced with word processors). Like leading, space before/after should be consistent (such as adhering to a baseline grid). For example, if you have a 6pt baseline grid, your font is 10/12 (meaning 10pt size, 12 pt leading), 6pt space after would align to the grid but 4pt would not.

If you are using InDesign, you can force paragraph styles to align to a baseline grids under "Indents and Spacing" in the Paragraph Options window for the style. To set the size of your grid, go to Edit > Preferences > Grids. (I believe the default baseline is 12pt). Scribus and other design software usually have similar features. There are plenty of resources for [using grids with InDesign](http://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/grids.html).

Consistent leading and leadings that are proportionally related give a sense of structure to a page. This helps the reader see text that is different, and since different text usually means something, it can help with comphrension too. Plus it looks nice.

Comment: Note that the main benefit of a baseline grid is when you are laying out type in columns. If you're not, there's not really a strong argument for the baseline grid (though it won't hurt, of course). Also, I'm always skeptical of resources that start off talking about the golden ratio. :)

Comment: @Da01: A strong argument for the baseline grid is so that lines of text on both sides of the page are aligned. For most printed matter, this doesn't matter, but you'll notice that any well-designed newspaper has this property. Why? Because of the way most people read newspapers when they're sitting on a chair: by holding them up in front of them. If there's a bright source of light in front of them (e.g. a window), then all the lines overlap each other and make it much harder to read. Most novels also share this property, though for novels I'm not sure it's intentional or simply a coincidence.